# "ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication" for Deploy Spring Boot app to Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have created a simple repository which has two functions:

1. Greets the user.
2. Asks for a username, saves it to the `postgresql` database, greets the user by this name.

When I test my application locally, it works correctly. But when I try to deploy it to Heroku, I get these errors:

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command java -Dserver.port=11441 $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar
app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
app[web.1]:     at com.pro.library.Application.main(Application.java:10)
app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
app[web.1]:     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
app[web.1]:     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
app[web.1]:     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

I have a feeling that the error is related to the creation of the jar, but I do not understand how to solve it. I have already looked at a bunch of articles on how to deploy to heroku, but so far this has not helped to identify my problem.

my Procfile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

my building.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
}

version = "0.0.1"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/milestone") }
    maven { url = uri("https://repo.spring.io/snapshot") }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.9")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.9")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26")
    implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.3.Final")
    annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.3.Final")

    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.4")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.5.13")
    implementation("com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.20.0")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.9")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.17.6")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.17.6")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            "Main-Class" to "com.pro.library.Application",
        )
    }
}
```

My Application.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which command do you use to build the application?

Comment: locally: standard `clean build`. But for heroku, I don't know where to set it

Comment: Most probably `build/libs/*.jar` will have two jars, one plain. Did you check the directory content?